# what I'm doing wrong

Tags: batch-file, sox

this is the batch

```
for /f "skip=9 tokens=1-3" %%x in ('sox.exe Heavyrainambienc2801.wav -n stat') do (
  if "%%x %%y"=="Maximum delta:" set maxDelta=%%z
)
echo %maxDelta%
```

and instead of max delta value I'm getting blank echo

```
Samples read:          11832320
Length (seconds):    123.253333
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.999939
Minimum amplitude:    -0.999969
Midline amplitude:    -0.000015
Mean    norm:          0.488960
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000082
RMS     amplitude:     0.570900
Maximum delta:         1.999878
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.651948
RMS     delta:         0.807396
Rough   frequency:        10804
Volume adjustment:        1.000

Try: -t raw -e mu-law -b 8

C:\1>echo
ECHO is on.
```

I'm not sure this is important but it is run on Windows 10

Comment: your code is fine. Is it [within another code-block](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)?

Comment: PLEASE provide a SPECIFIC question TITLE!! How is the output of `sox.exe` formatted -- ANSI/Unicode?

Comment: no, it is separate code, I don't know about formatting of the sox.exe

Comment: If you know that the line # 10 have the info you want, why do you add the `if` command? Just take the third token at such line...

Comment: I meant the **output** of `sox.exe`, not the application itself; try to do the following: `sox.exe Heavyrainambienc2801.wav -n stat > "\path\to\file.txt"`, then open the returned file `file.txt` with Notepad and go to "File » Save As..."; in the "Save As" dialog, what is selected in the "Encoding:" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the mistake is, but there is a workaround:
Place the output of the command you are using in a text-document and read it from there. That worked for me.

I directly copied the block of text into the file to test it; if there is something else you might want to check if %%x and %%y are the desired values. If they are not, you know where to take a closer look :)

At the end of the batch script, you can just delete the file.

```
@echo off
sox.exe Heavyrainambienc2801.wav -n stat 2>output.txt
for /f "skip=9 tokens=1-3" %%x in (output.txt) do (
if "%%x %%y"=="Maximum delta:" set maxDelta=%%z
)
echo %maxDelta%
del output.txt
pause
```

Comment: It's not working either. The output.txt file is blank :(

Comment: Oops! It might be there has been a space missing in front of `>output.txt`
That made a change with my test command...

Comment: It's also possible that you need to use `2>output.txt` instead; some programs output to STDERR instead of STDOUT.

Comment: If what you've posted in the original question is the output, then `sox` must be writing to STDERR as @SomethingDark suggests.

Comment: Oh, ok. I am not that far into batch; it just came into my mind as a workaround :)

Comment: 2>output.txt did the job. Thanks for all help